# Are there more boys born in the US?

Tags: mortality, gender, demographics

According to this [article](https://www.deseret.com/2022/5/5/23058610/pregnancy-more-girls-boys-sex-ratios-birth-infant-mortality-pew-cdc-world-bank-infection-miscarriage#:%7E:text=The%20United%20States%20is%20among,annually%20in%20the%20United%20States.) there are more boys born in the USA than girls.

> between 1940 and 2005, an average of almost 92,000 more males than females were born annually in the United States.

According to [city comparison,](https://www.bestplaces.net/compare-cities/) though, there are more women than men.

What is happening here? The only explanation could be that the men are dying earlier then women. Is this deviance across all ages or just in older age?

[image]

Comment: Women live longer on average than men. So extreme, you count women born in the last 80 years vs. men born in the last 70 years.

Comment: Don'f torget that the population of a country isn't a function only of birth and death; there is also immigration and emigration, which could be gender-imbalanced for many reasons.

Comment: @NateEldredge, you can write an answer and show us statistics proving there is more male immigrants(legal). But I think the statistics is based on the US citizens on residents.

Comment: @Grasper  Your commnet is illogcial.  Legal or illegal immigrants eventually are either deported or else become citziens or a lest reisdentsof hte USA tobe counted as US citizens or residents.  US citizens can emigrated to othre countries and then no longer be counted as residents, even if they retain citizenship.

Comment: @Grasper: AFAIK the term "population", unless otherwise specified, counts all inhabitants, without regard to citizenship or legal immigration status.  I don't have statistics on im/emigration by gender.  I'm just disagreeing with your assertion that men dying earlier is the "only explanation" and saying that you ought to consider the possibility of people entering/leaving while still alive.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to mention [Fisher's principle]}(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_principle): For purely logical reasons, birth ratios of males and females have an equilibrium at 1:1. More exactly, that ratio must concern the gender ratio of individuals reproducing, so that, as shown, skewed birth rates make up for inversely skewed childhood survival rates.

Comment: How is this a skeptics question? As you write yourself, the statistic that you show does not contradict the claim that is made. Why do you doubt the claim?

Comment: @CarstenS, the male birth rate and female population does contradict hence the doubt. I might not know the reason even if it's guessable.

Comment: There is no error allowance on that data. I mean, usually there is a +/-n% on data like that, because they didn't poll the whole population, but a part of it and then extrapolated. Serious data tells you that +/- figure. And sometimes it's more than the value they are fretting about.

Comment: @RedSonja Every ten years the united States conducts a census with the intent to survey the entire population. Though there are a few who fall through the cracks, there are mechanisms in place to account for those individuals. The result is that the [margin of error for the U.S. Census is in the order of +/- 0.25%](https://www.census.gov/newsroom/press-releases/2022/2020-census-estimates-of-undercount-and-overcount.html#:~:text=The%20PES%20found%20that%20the,not%20statistically%20different%20from%20zero.) That's less than 1/3 the difference between the male/female population nationwide.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This happens everywhere, not only in the USA, though the degree of disparity varies from country to country.

[Gender Ratio - Our World in Data](https://ourworldindata.org/gender-ratio) provides a lot of information on this topic.

The two most relevant details are:

> - Women, on average, live longer than men. This means that all else being equal, we would expect females to account for slightly more than half of the total population.
> - sex ratios at birth are not equal. In all countries, there are more male than female births.

> For most countries, there are around 105 males per 100 female births.

> the sex ratio at conception is equal: there is no difference in the number of males and females conceived. For births to be consistently male-biased, there must be gender differences in the probability of miscarriage through pregnancy.

That is, females are less likely than males to survive until birth, while after birth, males have a lower life expectancy than females.

While dangerous situations (e.g. employment, risky behaviour, and war) contribute to the male death rate, the difference becomes most significance at higher ages where these factors don't apply:

[image: Sex ratio by age]

Deliberate sex-selection may slightly contribute to the antenatal rates (as can be seen during certain periods in some countries), but is not the general cause:

[image: Sex ratio at birth]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140026/discussion-on-answer-by-ray-butterworth-are-there-more-boys-born-in-the-us).

Comment: Reminder: We don't care about your political views, and the comments box is not a place to share them.

Comment: "Risky behaviour" in youth, for example smoking or exposure to asbestos at work, or even sport, can affect death rates in later life.

Answer (score 4):

It is true that more boys are born ([here](https://www.infoplease.com/us/population/births-sex-and-sex-ratio) for figures from 1983 to 2008), but if you look at the following page

[Social Security Actuarial Life Table](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/STATS/table4c6.html)

you will readily see that in the United States, a male of any given age was more likely to die in 2019 than a female of the same age. The disparity (both relative and absolute) is smallest at age 10 (which is also the age with the lowest combined mortality). The disparity ramps up in the teenage years and reaches its relative peak in the early twenties. It declines after this point, but parity is not achieved until well past the age of 100.

That higher probability of dying, year over year, adds up; the table shows the math.

The causes? We know that young boys and young men are more prone to risky behavior (as the comment to the OP suggests). It is also known that [men suffer higher rates of suicide](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/suicide-death-rates-by-sex?country=%7EUSA), [are the victims of the majority of murders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homicide_statistics_by_gender), and comprise [over 90% of combat fatalities](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26101910/) and [occupational fatalities](https://www.statista.com/statistics/187127/number-of-occupational-injury-deaths-in-the-us-by-gender-since-2003/). I suspect that differing rates of [smoking](https://thesocietypages.org/graphicsociology/2012/08/21/global-smoking-rates-by-gender/), [drinking](https://arcr.niaaa.nih.gov/volume/40/2/gender-differences-epidemiology-alcohol-use-and-related-harms-united-states), and [on-the-job exposure to environmental hazards](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34839446/) are also involved.

Comment: A major (albeit contrary) cause of gender disparity is that in less developed nations, many women [die in childbirth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_maternal_mortality_ratio), and when there is less access to contraception/abortion they give birth more often, increasing the risk.

Comment: @Stuart. I'm probably going to delete the references to other countries, as it's not really germane.